# Can I get away with testing sites using IE8 with IE7 compatibility on?

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

As a developer, can I safely upgrade to IE8 and use its IE7 compatibility mode to test how sites look in IE7? For IE6, I have a virtual machine and it is quite inconvenient. I don't want to upgrade to IE8 and then have another virtual machine now for IE7.

Or is IE7 compatibility mode really different and I can't rely on that?

Comment: Why do you need virtual machines? Can't you just install two versions alongside each other?

Comment: With risky hacks, yes. But not a good idea unless your're feeling lucky.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compatibility mode in IE8 is not a 100% emulation of IE7. Security changes were not versioned, and some DOM operations were not versioned. Check out this blog post form Microsoft for a list of changes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft is developing a tool called [Expression Web SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en) to make it easier to test for the growing fauna of browsers.

Blog entries describing it by [Long Zheng](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090318/expression-web-superpreview-cross-browser-testing/) and [The Expression Web Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/xweb/archive/2009/03/18/Microsoft-Expression-Web-SuperPreview-for-Windows-Internet-Explorer.aspx).

Comment: this thing is not ready yet, read the Long Zheng's article before you download it. the concept is good though

Comment: @rm: Yes, that's why i wrote that MS is developing it.

Answer (score 3):

You should try using [**IE Tester**](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) - a life saver. It lets you view a website on IE 5.5, 6, 7, current installed version, and 8 beta all in one program - each browser version loads in it's own tab and can be split screen etc.

Answer (score 1):

The MSHTML code changed.  IE7 compat mode should be pretty damn close to IE7, but... the code changed.  I would still test both.

Microsoft makes [Virtual PC images available](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) for testing this.

Comment: I see that the VPC images expire after about a month. Are they refreshed from time to time?

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that IE7 and IE8 (compatibility mode) are not the same. In my case it was CSS problem that showed up in IE7 and not in IE8

Answer (score 0):

I use IE7 compatibility mode and it serves me all right. Did you try Multiple IE http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE instead of using a virtual machine?

Comment: MultipleIE doesn't have IE7 in it, and IE6 doesn't work properly with IE8 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget IETab for Firefox... making things that little bit easier. Though IIRC, you can only use this to test the version that's default on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Microsoft has finally released Expression Web SuperPreview

It can be downloaded here

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Multiple IEs was listed in another answer.

There's a successor to "Multiple IEs" called [Internet Explorer Collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm) that is more up to date.