# Is IE8 backwards compatible?

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, compatibility

Hopefully some has some knowledge of this.

I'm fast realising that IE8 certainly can't be ignored anymore.  I had previously  put it down to either a) just a buggy piece of software, or b) still to small a piece of the market share.  Now, however, I'm seeing more and more requirement to make sure sites work on it.

My question is can I switch over to testing on IE8 only and safely 'believe' that the resulting code will still work on IE7?

Any thoughts/knowledge would be helpful. Cheers.

Comment: Is this a rant or a question? No offense, but if you want it to work on IE7 you'll have to test it on IE7.

Comment: definitely a question.  comes as a result of a string of clients unexpectedly testing in ie8 and having to please them.  Wondering how vastly different they are..

Comment: Clearly, you should have skipped the "IE8 is ready blah blah" part and just ask "If I test my app on IE8, can I assume that it works on IE7?", which has an obvious answer, that I gave below.

Comment: skip the whole question, just code with webstandards in mind including JS and AJAX and you won't have any problem.

Comment: See also the related (or close to duplicate) questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712055/can-i-get-away-with-testing-sites-using-ie8-with-ie7-compatibility-on and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908216/if-ie8-is-installed-how-can-i-test-ie6-and-ie7-compatibility. You'll find good answers there.

Comment: @dusoft: I'd say code with web standards in mind _and_ test your app. @David, you're welcome :)

Comment: To the three closers: "can I switch over to testing on IE8 only and safely 'believe' that the resulting code will still work on IE7?" looks quite like a real question to me.

Comment: @dusoft: Not to mention, coding to web standards will break in IE 6:)

Answer (score 11):

> My question is can I switch over to
>   testing on IE8 only and safely
>   'believe' that the resulting code will
>   still work on IE7?

No.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the day where I can write "No." as an answer and get up-voted for it. :)

Comment: You just need to write it quick enough ;-)

Comment: I have upgraded my browser to IE8 and have so far noticed no differences between IE7 and IE8 running in IE7 mode.

Comment: Another tip is to quote the original question, otherwise SO doesn't let you post a three-character answer :)

Comment: @kim3er: When developing professional applications it is important that, if your requirement is that it runs on X, Y and Z, you test it on X, Y and Z.

Comment: Thankfully as a "Professional Developer" I do just that and so far I have noticed "no differences between IE7 and IE8 in IE7 mode".

I had hoped the last part of that statement would imply that I'm actively comparing the two browsers.

Comment: @Tomalak: I feel the same way!

Comment: @kim3er: You may have compared them, but still you have to trust that IE8's emulation of IE7 is perfect, and a better alternative, which is testing directly on IE7, exists. mbenny points out some actual differences here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712055/can-i-get-away-with-testing-sites-using-ie8-with-ie7-compatibility-on/712087#712087

Answer (score 10):

No, IE8 is *radically* different from IE7. And it's radically different from any other decent browser too, so you can't rely on other tests...

And yes, it's installed in enough machines now that we *need* to test for it too already.

The good news is that now IETester actually works (it didn't work *at all* for me a few months ago, it wouldn't even load) so definitely give it a shot, even if you tried it before and it didn't work for you. And definitely test in the 3 versions.

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: thanks, this is the kind of knowledge I don't have and am I'm looking for

Comment: There are differences between IE7 and IE8/Compatibility7. The feature is decent for fixing up broken sites for end users, it isn't good enough to substitute for testing in IE7 for developers.

Comment: @David: Really? Uh-Oh....
Looks like i'll be creating a new VM :-(
Thanks for that

Comment: With Windows 7 you can have VMs that run in the background while the applications run in the foreground, so that you can have two XP VMs running IE7 and IE6 but only see the IE7 and IE6 Windows on your desk.

Answer (score 6):

You can force IE8 to render pages as IE7, which can provide a ***workaround***, since IE7 and IE8 can't cohabitate.  Just add the following tag into the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

Microsoft also provides this tag to be either added into the HTTP header or the site's header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

Microsoft has more information on using the tag on the [developer readiness](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-new.aspx#versioning) page.

My understanding is that the entire IE7 rendering engine is left intact in IE8, so sites can just add in those headers and have it drop down to the IE7 mode.  However, changes were made to the DOM and for security that were not backported to IE7, so the transition isn't perfect.

Firefox/Safari/Chrome/Opera/etc. completely ignore this tag.  There's a great write up at [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/issues/251).

Comment: emphasis on "workaround"... sticking with IE7's poor standards support in the long run is asking for trouble.  As for the meta tag, any non-IE8 browser will ignore it.

Comment: Microsoft.com uses this workaround. :)

Comment: @scunliffe: thanks for the note on how other browsers handle it, i'll update the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Whether IE8 is ready or not is not a valid reason to ignore it for testing. It is becoming used widespread. Therefore if you want high coverage of your websites then you should test them thoroughly in all major browsers. This includes IE7 AND IE8, reagardless of any compatibility options.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch over to IE8 and do compatibility tests targeting IE7 in IE8's compatibility mode.

Comment: ...Or sort of. Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712055/can-i-get-away-with-testing-sites-using-ie8-with-ie7-compatibility-on/712087#712087

Answer (score 1):

For an easy way to test in browsers, check out [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) (and debugbar at the same link).  It emulates IE 5.5 on up.  I personally still use IE7 (as its what most of my clients use) but check compatibility in IE Tester for 6 (yes, still have clients using 6) and 8.  I don't think it covers all compatability issues but I haven't yet run into a problem for my purposes.

I also asume you are testing for Firefox and other non-IE browsers.